# Given a string s that contains only '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', determine whether the string is valid

Tags: java, string

I want to write a function that does the following: Given a string s that contains only '(', ')', '{', '}', '[', ']', determine whether the string is valid. A valid string needs to satisfy:

- the opening parenthesis must be closed with the same type of closing parenthesis.
- Opening parentheses must be closed in the correct order.
- Each closing parenthesis has a corresponding opening parenthesis of the same type.

Example:

Input: s = "()"
Output: true

Input: s = "()[]{}"
Output: true

Input: s = "(]"
Output: false.

But when I test the code with:
Input "()"
Output is showing as false.

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        Map<String, String> map = Map.of("(",")","[","]","{","}");

        if (s.length() % 2 != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < s.length() / 2; index++) {
            if (!map.containsKey(s.charAt(2 * index + 1))) {
                return false;
            } else {
                if (!map.get(s.charAt(2 * index + 1)).equals(s.charAt(2 * index + 2))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The function may be realized by using the stack, but the first thing I thought of was my method. Where is the logic error in my method?

Comment: When I run your code for "()" - it gives a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2` - not false. Do you have a typo somewhere ?

Comment: what is the expected result for `([])` ?

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=valid+parentheses)?  Also, it is on coding practice / challenge sites. There is [one at LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have 2 issues:

1. Your code assumes `charAt()` takes index values from 1 onwards. It does not - it takes values from 0
2. Your code assumes there is no nesting. So, it won't work for cases like `[()]`

Comment: Yep, I wrote it wrong - thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

One additional issue that is not addressed in the first answer is that you are attempting to access a `Map<String, String>` with a `char`. `charAt()` returns a character and the keys in the map are strings. This can be fixed by updating the map to be `Map<Character, Character>`, or by getting the string value of the character (such as by using `String.valueOf()`) wherever you are getting the character at a certain index.

This combined with addressing the issues laid out in Abdeali's answer should fix your issue.